# Azure WebJobs not listing in Azure Kudo Portal

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobs-triggered

I'm trying to edit my configuration `app.config` from the Azure WebJob. I currently have 2 web jobs that configured to run as on-demand (Cron Scheduled)

[image]

My Jobs are working perfectly fine. But When I try to view the source code of my web jobs through `Kudo Command`

https://xxxxx.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole

[image]

I'm not able to see any jobs for the trigger. In fact, there is no folder called `triggered`

but when I tried to `https://xx.scm.azurewebsites.net/azurejobs/#/jobs` I can able to see my Jobs there.

**How to find the source code of my WebJobs?**

Comment: I appreciate the kind and quick comeback!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default location for WebJobs is under `d:\home\site\wwwroot\App_Data\jobs`. Did you look there?

Comment: Thanks, Got it there. May I know what is the difference between `d:\home\site\jobs` and `d:\home\site\wwwroot\App_Data\jobs` ?

Comment: `d:\home\site\wwwroot\App_Data\jobs` is the default. `d:\home\site\jobs` is a fallback used when trying to upload a new WebJob while [running from a package](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/84), where the `wwwroot` forlder is read-only.

Comment: I have an issue with this structure since all the web jobs were deployed under `d:\home\site\wwwroot\App_Data\jobs` i need to deploy my webjobs for every build/release but i don't want this to be deployed for every build/release. Since we are using CI/CD we will only deploy the webjobs if any changes in that WebJobs. Is there is any way to achieve this ?